# jQuery Function don't work with two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

My jQuery script don't return the number in ascending order.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.xpto = function(dom, speed) {
    i = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      $(dom).append(i + '<br>');
    }, speed);
  };

  $.xpto('#a', 1000);
  $.xpto('#b', 2000);
});
```

**And my HTML:**

```
<div id="a" style="background:blue;float:left;"></div>
<div id="b" style="background:red;float:left;"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `var` keyword before `i = 0` and `interval`. This causes all instances of function `$.xpto` to share these variables. Furthermore, the `i` variable resets to zero each time you call `$.xpto`.

According to your function's logic, this should happen:

```
a 1
b 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
b 6
a 7
a 8
b 9
...
```

If this is not as expected, mention your wishes, and I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/hWYG5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.xpto = function(dom, speed) {
        var i = 0;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            i++;
            $(dom).append(i + '<br>');
        }, speed);
    };

    $.xpto('#a', 1000);
    $.xpto('#b', 2000);
});
```

Without the `var` keyword, the variable i is not getting declared explicitly within the closure and is being reused within both the calls to `$.xpto`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to give each row its own count variable then you must use the var keyword before defining i.

http://jsfiddle.net/pF2ef/2/